# Ubuntu 18.04 backup not working

Tags: backup

When I try to backup my Ubuntu 18.04 I get the following message: "Backup Failed - failed with an unknown error" and then the following is shown:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1555, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1541, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1393, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1516, in do_backup
    full_backup(col_stats)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 572, in full_backup
    globals.backend)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 454, in write_multivol
    (tdp, dest_filename, vol_num)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/asyncscheduler.py", line 146, in schedule_task
    return self.__run_synchronously(fn, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/asyncscheduler.py", line 172, in __run_synchronously
    ret = fn(*params)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 453, in <lambda>
    vol_num: put(tdp, dest_filename, vol_num),
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 342, in put
    backend.put(tdp, dest_filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 395, in inner_retry
    % (n, e.__class__.__name__, util.uexc(e)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/util.py", line 79, in uexc
    return ufn(unicode(e).encode('utf-8'))
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)
```

==========================

I am using the backup utility that comes with the Ubuntu 18.04 package, named "Backups". I am backing up to an ext hard drive - Toshiba 2Tb. It has worked in the past but recently (a week ago) this problem has arisen. I have done nothing unusual that I know of.

I should be most grateful for any help. Please remember I am 70 years old and a noob!
Thanking you in anticipation.
DB

Comment: Can you [edit] and add some details about what you are trying to do? Such as where you are trying to back up to, if you are using deja-dup (the Backups app), etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am using the backup utility that comes with the Ubuntu 18.04 package, named "Backups".  I am backing up to an ext hard drive - Toshiba 2Tb.  It has worked in the past but recently (a week ago) this problem has arisen.  I have done nothing unusual that I know of.

Comment: Are you able to restore any files?  If your backup drive is connected, you can right-click on a file in the file manager and select "revert to previous version", then Backups will try to restore it (after asking you a series of questions about where to get the file, etc). (You could copy/rename the file first just to be safe).

Comment: The `ascii` error message in the last line suggests you might have encountered this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/duplicity/+bug/1770929  If I read it correctly, it happens when there are non-ASCII characters passed to the program. This could happen if you are specifically including or excluding directories or files that have nonASCII characters in their names - the example given in the bug report is ä

Comment: Errr - OK - not sure what I do about it then?

Comment: Yes, when I right-click on a file the option of restore to previous version is offered.  But I can't to this for each of the thousands of files (for logistical reasons).

Comment: I can restore from last backup - August 2 - but will I lose files added between then and now?

Comment: I am not suggesting you do a mass restore. I was just trying to find out if your backup / restore software was working at all.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Not sure where to go from here then.  Should I reinstall Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: I would look for nonASCII characters.

Comment: Sorry - I'm a novice - don't know what you mean by "I would look for nonASCII characters".  How would I look for them and what would I do when I find them?

Comment: Non-ASCII are generally foreign characters like Russian, Chinese, Japanese, ...  anything positively *weird* to you. (My apologies to the Russian, Chinese, Japanese users on this site.  **;-)** YKWIM...)  Find the file / directory that has them and rename it / them...

Comment: Good - thanks - found them - the offending characters were:  ":" and "?" - erroneously entered at some time.  Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately I ditched "Backup" app and now use "Grsync" (GUI)  and Rsync for the terminal.  Also, reported errors related to use of colon < : > and < ? > in file names - once corrected all fine.
Sincere thanks to those who helped - greatly appreciated!